# Error with sbt-assembly and Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-assembly

Trying to build a fat jar of a play (2.6.6) + scala.js application, getting

> [error] (play/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>   [error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.12/jars/play_2.12-2.6.6.jar:play/reference-overrides.conf
>   [error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-akka-http-server_2.12/jars/play-akka-http-server_2.12-2.6.6.jar:play/reference-overrides.conf

`build.sbt`

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("play.core.server.ProdServerStart")
//fullClasspath in assembly += Attributed.blank(PlayKeys.playPackageAssets.value)
```

(Inspired by https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.6/Deploying#Using-the-SBT-assembly-plugin)

(but not using playPackageAssets at the moment)

my `assembly.sbt` contains just `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")`

I also tried with a "non-standard" config:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
// Building fat jar without META-INF
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
// Take last config file
case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".conf" => MergeStrategy.last
case o =>
  val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
  oldStrategy(o)
}
```

but no luck either. How to fix that the/a correct way?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `sbt-assembly` how to merge these two `reference-overrides.conf` config files:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
// Building fat jar without META-INF
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
// Take last config file
case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".conf" => MergeStrategy.last
case PathList("reference-overrides.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
case o =>
  val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
  oldStrategy(o)
}
```

Comment: Actually I thought that the line before that the one with `endsWith ".conf"` would take care of that (Yes, I see that it doesn't concat!) but alas... thanks!

Comment: Still gives me the exact same error message though :( (yes, sbt was refreshed)

Comment: @Sorona I think we're getting the path wrong. Try: `case "reference-overrides.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat`

Comment: Same, but maybe we are looking for the wrong file somehow? `[warn] Merging 'reference.conf' with strategy 'concat'
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge` -> and then it shows the path to `reference-overrides.conf`

Comment: @Sorona Ok, thats good, that means it finds the file. What does the error say?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I explained that wrongly. It's the exact same error as before. I also tried to add a `println` "log" there, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by adding the following to .

```
case PathList("play", "reference-overrides.conf")  => MergeStrategy.concat
```